# When did satan (SH7835) obtain the second meaning of superhuman adversary?

Tags: satan, hebrew, word-study

For Strong's Hebrew number 7854 (Satan) the Brown-Driver-Briggs' notes give these meanings:

> (1) adversary, one who withstands
>
> (1a) adversary (in general — personal or national)
>
> (2) superhuman adversary
>
> (2a) Satan (as noun proper)

And Strong gives us:

> From H7853; an opponent; especially (with the article prefixed) Satan,
> the arch enemy of good: - adversary, Satan, withstand.

Whereas SH7834 has:

> A primitive root; to attack, (figuratively) accuse: - (be an)
> adversary, resist.

The first meaning of SH7835 seems to agree with the root form. The second sticks out as quite a bit different.

Can anyone explain where this second meaning (superhuman adversary & proper noun) comes from (ideally with sources I can go and look at) and from what point in time this second meaning might have been contemporarily understood?

Comment: Revelation 12:9 points to Genesis 3 so, it's an old idea.

Comment: We have a whole site dedicated to [hermeneutics.se], which might be a better fit for this.

Comment: @DJClayworth thank you, I will take a look.